# MySQL database structure to store items with multiple available options

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, checkbox, insert-update

I asked this question earlier but couldnt find answer.. First of all sorry for my english..

I have a form  include 80 checkboxes  : these checkboxes are options for car  ,
example for car ;  Mp3 Player | ABS | Airbag | Air conditioning |

User should select his own cars options from checkboxes and post it..  The question is ? How should i store them in database?  By the way  user should able to update them later..

Should i use  implode() and store them like

```
option1 , option2 , option34 , option45 , option66 ,  in one column
```

or  like that

```
Car_ID | Options | 
155      option2
155      option34
155      option45
155      option66
```

( How should they update them? )

or open 80 column in database  and like ,

```
Car_ID | Option1 | Option2 | Option3 | Option4 | Option5
155         true     true      false     false     false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have an options table, a users table, and a user_options table that relates them. This will allow you to easily modify the options as necessary and add or remove options.

```
Users
user_id,username

Options
option_id,option_name

User Options
option_id,user_id
```

if each user can have multiple cars it should be:

```
Users
user_id,username

Options
option_id,option_name

Cars
car_id,car_name

User_Car_Options
user_id,car_id,option_id
```

Comment: how should they update options_?  for example  user checked Mp3 Player  by mistaken and post it , then he unchecked it .. ?

Comment: There are lots of ways to do it on the front end. To be user friendly, I would use AJAX if possible and bind an event to the checkbox change event. Then I would submit a 1 or a 0 to my application and do the backend stuff. Ideally the user id would be stored in the session, and the car id should be submitted also from a hidden input field.

Answer (score 0):

best way is like that

```
+---------+----------+----------+----------+
| Car_ID  | Option1  | Option2  | Option3  |
+---------+----------+----------+----------+
| 1       | TRUE     | FALSE    | NULL     |
| 2       | TRUE     | NULL     | FALSE    |
| 3       | NULL     | TRUE     | FALSE    |
+---------+----------+----------+----------+
```

(If you feel this would clutter your original table, you could also simply put these columns in a separate table and set up a 1:N relationship between them)

**EDIT :**

But, if the checkboxes are dynamic, and you want to be able to add/remove boxes from the list, you may want to set up a N:M relationship, where each row in your table could have a value for each checkbox.
This would require a separate table to store the ceckboxes, and an intermediary table to store the values each row in table A has for each checkbox.
Like:

```
/* Your table */
+-----+
| AID | 
+-----+ 
| 1   |
| 2   |
| 3   | 
+-----+

/* The table for the boxes */
+-------+-------+
| BoxID | Label |
+-------+-------+
| 1     | Box1  |
| 2     | Box2  |
| 3     | Box3  |
+-------+-------+

/* The intermediary table 
 * linking them together */
+-----+-------+-------+
| AID | BoxID | Value |
+-----+-------+-------+
| 1   | 1     | TRUE  |
| 1   | 2     | FALSE |
| 2   | 1     | TRUE  |
| 2   | 3     | FALSE |
| 3   | 2     | TRUE  |
| 3   | 3     | FALSE |
+-----+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Might work for some applications, but not best practice. See Ethan's idea.